# How to add ajax data in attribute in td element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

In my ajax datatable I have this initialized:

```
"ajax": {
    "url": "{{ route('cust_continfo_data_table') }}",
    "dataType": "json",
    "type": "POST",
    "data": {
        _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
        cust_id_copy: $("#cust_id_copy").val()
    }
},
"columnDefs": [{
        'targets': 4,
        'createdCell': function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
            $(td).attr('title', 'columns');
        }
    }
],
"columns": [{
        "data": "id"
    }, {
        "data": "receipt_date"
    }, {
        "data": "info_division_name"
    }, {
        "data": "contact_status"
    }, {
        "data": "note"
    }, {
        "data": "created_at"
    }, {
        "data": "updated_at"
    }
],
```

As you can see, I only have static value assigned which is `colum`n in:

```
$(td).attr('title', 'columns');
```

How can I add the dynamic value from `"data":"note"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rowData` object should have the property `note`

```
'createdCell': function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
     $(td).attr('title', rowData.note);
}
```